# Conversion of String like "asdfgh" to integer value

Tags: java, string, integer

I want to convert the string like "asdfgh" not like a "2345",
I know we can convert "2345" by using : Integer.parseInt("stringOfNumber");
but i have to convert "asdfgg" to intger value in java.

please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well what number would you want "asdfgg" to convert to, and why?

Comment: so like, hashing it, or taking the char array and typecasting those into integers?

Comment: actually i like to convert my log-event message into integer for calculate there distance for clustering. I represent message by binary value in string format, finally i have to compare there distance by numeric form. thanks @JonSkeet

Comment: for cluster similar event together.

Comment: @SanjayaPandey: Distance in what sense? You can compute a distance *between* strings with something like Levenshtein, but it's not clear how you'd expect just a simple number to work. You really need to provide a lot more information in the question. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Do you mean something like a Soundex? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method [hashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode%28%29), this will return a int value for any string according with the documentation.

> Returns a hash code for this string. The hash code for a String object is computed as
>
> ```
> s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
> ```
>
> using int arithmetic, where s[i] is the ith character of the string, n is the length of the string, and ^ indicates exponentiation. (The hash value of the empty string is zero.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to convert the string to ascii, you would do:

```
String randomString = "asdfgh";  
byte[] asciiString = randomString.getBytes("US-ASCII");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're question is unclear, but you might want this-

```
    String str = "Abcdefg";
    char[] cArray = str.toCharArray();
    int result=0;

    for (int i=0; i<cArray.length; i++){
        result+=cArray[i]*Math.pow(10,i);
    }

    System.out.println(result);
```